# Call factory function once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this factory which is called multiple times by directives. Since it returns a lot of data the rendering at the end is slow. How can i call it only once or save it in a cashe when its called the second time and n time?

```
appBMdata.factory('Trends',['$http','Config','$q',
    function($http,Config,$q){


           function getAllData() {
            var source1 = $http.get(Config.api_server + 'bizmonitor/indicators/get/2016');
            var source2 = $http.post(Config.api_server + 'trends');

            return $q.all([source1, source2]);

          };

          return {
            getAllData : getAllData,
          };     
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the promise in a var, and return it if it has been already set:

```
appBMdata.factory('Trends',['$http','Config','$q',
  function($http,Config,$q){

         var _cacheGetAllData;
         function getAllData() {
          var source1 = $http.get(Config.api_server + 'bizmonitor/indicators/get/2016');
          var source2 = $http.post(Config.api_server + 'trends');

          _cacheGetAllData = _cacheGetAllData || $q.all([source1, source2]);
          return _cacheGetAllData;
        }

        return {
          getAllData : getAllData,
        };     
}]);
```

If you want successive calls to force to update, you can edit it to something like this:

```
appBMdata.factory('Trends',['$http','Config','$q',
  function($http,Config,$q){
    var _cacheGetAllData;
    function getAllData(ignoreCache) {
      var source1 = $http.get(Config.api_server + 'bizmonitor/indicators/get/2016');
      var source2 = $http.post(Config.api_server + 'trends');

      if (ignoreCache) {_cacheGetAllData = undefined;}
      _cacheGetAllData = _cacheGetAllData || $q.all([source1, source2]);
      return _cacheGetAllData;
    }

    return {
      getAllData : getAllData,
    };     
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can keep the data on `$rootScope` and return the data from there when its called multiple times.

```
appBMdata.factory('Trends',['$http','Config','$q','$rootScope'
    function($http,Config,$q,$rootScope){


           function getAllData() {
            var source1 = $http.get(Config.api_server + 'bizmonitor/indicators/get/2016');
            var source2 = $http.post(Config.api_server + 'trends');

            return $q.all([source1, source2]);

          };
          if($rootScope.data){             // check if data already present
            $rootScope.data=getAllData();    // assign data to rootscope
          }
          return {
           getAllData : $rootScope.data,   //return data from rootscope
          };
  }]);
```

Comment: After trying your code update when i call the service Trends.getAllData() i get an error : 'Trends.getAllData is not a function'. Is there a different way i should call the service ?

Comment: @AntonioGocaj.. you should be just calling  `Trends.getAllData`

Comment: @AntonioGocaj.. sorry I had a typo.. fixed

Answer (score 1):

I'm resolving it in the service and then store data, if it has data, returning data in a promise. If you want to fetch data again just add true as first arguement.

```
appBMdata.factory('Trends', ['$http', 'Config', '$q', function($http, Config, $q) {

    var data;

    function getAllData(nocache) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (data.length && !nocache) {

           deferred.resolve(data);

        } else {

            var source1 = $http.get(Config.api_server + 'bizmonitor/indicators/get/2016');
            var source2 = $http.post(Config.api_server + 'trends');

            $q.all([source1, source2])
                .then(function (values) {
                    data = values;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });
        }

        return deferred.promise;

    }

    return {
        getAllData : getAllData
    };

}]);
```